# SQLAclhemy, auroa-serverless invalid transaction issue on commit (aurora_data_api.exceptions.DatabaseError)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using the [sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api://) to connect to aurora-postgresql-serverless, with SQLalchemy as an ORM.

For the most part, this has been working fine, but I keep hitting unexpected errors from the aurora_data_api (which sqlalchemy-aurora-data-api is built upon) during commits.

I've tried to handle this in the application logic by catching the exception and re-trying, however, this is still failing:

```py
from aurora_data_api.exceptions import DatabaseError
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def handle_invalid_transaction_id(func):
    retries = 3

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(retries):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except (DatabaseError, ClientError):
                if i != retries:
                    # The aim here is to try and force a new transaction 
                    # If an error occurs and retry
                    db.session.close()
                else:
                    raise

    return inner
```

And then in my models doing something like this:

```py
class MyModel(db.Model):
    @classmethod
    @handle_invalid_transaction_id
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        instance = cls(**kwargs)
        db.session.add(instance)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()
        return kwargs
```

However, I keep hitting unpredictable transaction failures:

DatabaseError: (aurora_data_api.exceptions.DatabaseError) An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Transaction AXwQlogMJsPZgyUXCYFg9gUq4/I9FBEUy1zjMTzdZriEuBCF44s+wMX7+aAnyyJH/6arYcHxbCLW73WE8oRYsPMN17MOrqWfUdxkZRBrM/vBUfrP8FKv6Phfr6kK6o7/0mirCtRJUxDQAQPotaeP+hHj6/IOGUCaOnodt4M3015c0dAycuqhsy4= is not found [+26ms]

It is worth noting that these are not particularly long-running transactions, so I do not think that I'm hitting the transaction expiry issue that can occur with aurora-serverless as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html).

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach to this or is there a better way to handle transactions failures when they occur?

Answer (score 1):

Just to close this off, and in case it helps anyone else, found the issue was in the transactions that were being created by in the cursor [here](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/aurora-data-api/blob/509cefe2645af0d9cc21449fb739a18b13410062/aurora_data_api/__init__.py#L70)

I can't answer the why, but we noticed that transactions were expiring despite the fact the data successfully committed. e.g:

request 1 - creates a bunch of transactions, write data, exits.
request 2 - creates a bunch of transactions, some transaction id for request 1 fails, exits.

So yeah, I don't think the issue is with the `aurora-data-api`, but somehow to do with transaction mgmt in general in aurora-serverless. In the end, we forked the repo and refactored so that everything is handled with [ExecuteStatment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rdsdataservice/latest/APIReference/API_ExecuteStatement.html) calls rather than using transactions. It's been working fine so far (note we're using SQLalchemy so transactions are handled at the ORM level anyway).